# Why does this function always return the last filled element in the arrays?

Tags: vb.net

```
Structure WeightElement
    Dim LowPointer As Integer
    Dim HighPointer As Integer
    Dim Values As WeightedTrait()
    Dim Num As Integer 
End Structure
Structure WeightedTrait
    Dim TraitName As String
    Dim TraitNum As Integer
    Dim WeightValue As Decimal
End Structure

Function ExtractWeights(ByRef Tree As WeightElement(), ByRef Category As Integer, ByRef Trait As Integer, ByVal NeedsTrait As Boolean)
    Dim Pointer As Integer = 0
    Dim NotFound As Boolean = True
    While NotFound
        If Tree(Pointer).Num = Category Then
            NotFound = False
        ElseIf Tree(Pointer).Num > Category Then
            Pointer = Tree(Pointer).LowPointer
        ElseIf Tree(Pointer).Num < Category Then
            Pointer = Tree(Pointer).HighPointer
        End If
    End While
    If NeedsTrait Then
        NotFound = True
        While NotFound
            If Tree(Pointer).Num = Trait Then
                NotFound = False
            ElseIf Tree(Pointer).Num > Trait Then
                Pointer = Tree(Pointer).LowPointer
            ElseIf Tree(Pointer).Num < Trait Then
                Pointer = Tree(Pointer).HighPointer
            End If
        End While
    End If
    Return Tree(Pointer).Values
End Function

Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim Log(1) As WeightedTrait
    Log(0).TraitName = "xxxx"
    Log(0).TraitNum = 0
    Log(0).WeightValue = 0
    Dim Test(40) As WeightElement
    Test(0).LowPointer = 1
    Test(0).HighPointer = 2
    Test(0).Num = 1
    Test(0).Values = Log
    Test(0).Values(0).TraitName = "1"
    Test(1).LowPointer = 0
    Test(1).HighPointer = 0
    Test(1).Num = 0
    Test(1).Values = Log
    Test(1).Values(0).TraitName = "0"
    Test(2).LowPointer = 0
    Test(2).HighPointer = 0
    Test(2).Num = 2
    Test(2).Values = Log
    Test(2).Values(0).TraitName = "2"
    Test(20).LowPointer = 0
    Test(20).HighPointer = 0
    Test(20).Num = 3
    Test(20).Values = Log
    Test(20).Values(0).TraitName = "3"
    MsgBox(ExtractWeights(Test, 0, -1, False)(0).TraitName)
End Sub
```

The function, when I run it with the sub below it, always seems to return the last element of the array with a displayable value. Here, it should go to the second element and output 0, yet it somehow makes its way up to 20, for no reason that I can see

I have no idea why it is doing this. Does anyone else know how I might fix this?

Comment: Could you imagine if the issue were in the `WeightElement` or `WeightedTrait` classes? Do they relate to each other? How would we know?

Comment: @Enigmativity I've added them in

Comment: Thank you. To start with, I'd use `Found` not `NotFound`. It's easy to get confused with the not not.

Comment: Also, you don't have a tree. Trees are recursive structures.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `Values` property of each element of the `Test` array to the same instance of `Log`.

```
Test(0).Values = Log
Test(1).Values = Log
Test(2).Values = Log
Test(20).Values = Log
```

Then, for each one, you set the zeroth value of `TraitName`.

```
Test(0).Values(0).TraitName = "1"
Test(1).Values(0).TraitName = "0"
Test(2).Values(0).TraitName = "2"
Test(20).Values(0).TraitName = "3"
```

Since `Values` is the same array you're updating all of them to finally be on `"3"`.

You need to create distinct instances of the array for this to work.

Try this:

```
Private Function CreateWeightedTraitArray(ByVal TraitName As String) As WeightedTrait()
    Dim Log(0) As WeightedTrait
    Log(0).TraitName = TraitName
    Log(0).TraitNum = 0
    Log(0).WeightValue = 0
    Return Log
End Function

Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim Test(40) As WeightElement
    Test(0).LowPointer = 1
    Test(0).HighPointer = 2
    Test(0).Num = 1
    Test(0).Values = CreateWeightedTraitArray("1")
    Test(1).LowPointer = 0
    Test(1).HighPointer = 0
    Test(1).Num = 0
    Test(1).Values  = CreateWeightedTraitArray("0")
    Test(2).LowPointer = 0
    Test(2).HighPointer = 0
    Test(2).Num = 2
    Test(2).Values  = CreateWeightedTraitArray("2")
    Test(20).LowPointer = 0
    Test(20).HighPointer = 0
    Test(20).Num = 3
    Test(20).Values = CreateWeightedTraitArray("3")
    MsgBox(ExtractWeights(Test, 0, -1, False)(0).TraitName)
End Sub
```